# Getting data using query in access database, dataset shows old data

Tags: vb.net, dataset, updating

I'm using this code below to return some data from an access database using a query with a parameter passed to it:

```
    Dim con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(GlobalVariables.connectionString)
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    cmd.CommandText = "Q_VIEW_SINGLE_TEST"
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@TEST_ID", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = "17"  ' Add Parameter
    cmd.Connection = con
    con.Open()
    Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
    Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet()
    da.Fill(ds, "Table1")
    dt = ds.Tables("Table1")

    MsgBox(ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)(3))
```

It just keeps returning the old data however (so the data which was being returned when value was equal to 1:

```
   cmd.Parameters.Add("@TEST_ID", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = "1"
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you sure that the field used for the comparison with the parameter @TEST_ID is a string field? And could you post the code of the query "Q_VIEW_SINGLE_TEST"?

Comment: Make sure you are pointing towards the correct database.

Comment: Just try `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TEST_ID", "17")`

Comment: is the Access DB file open?

Comment: yes access was open, tried with it being closed same result, tried "cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TEST_ID", "17")" same result :(

Comment: code for query:

SELECT TESTS.TEST_ID, TESTS.MODULE_NO, TESTS.TEST_NAME, TESTS.TEST_DESCRIPTION, TESTS.AUTHOR, TESTS.PATH, TESTS.CUSTOM_BATCH, METRICS_EXPECTED.STANDARD_CHK, METRICS_EXPECTED.BITMAP_CHK, METRICS_EXPECTED.TEXT_CHK, METRICS_EXPECTED.TEXT_AREA_CHK, METRICS_EXPECTED.REPORTER_CHK
FROM TESTS INNER JOIN METRICS_EXPECTED ON TESTS.TEST_ID = METRICS_EXPECTED.TEST_ID;